# string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I converted MVC 3.5 to MVC2 4.0, get an error The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments
Here is my code:

```
<% if (this.Model.VisitId == 0) { %>
        mustSave = true;
    <% } else { %>
        mustSave = false;
    <% } %>
    <% if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationSummary())) { %>
        dataChanged = false;
    <% } else { %>
        dataChanged = true;
    <% } %>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the type of `ValidationSummary()`?

Comment: Looks like `string` to me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460343%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: All the methods require a param...his does not pass a param...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460185(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Does String.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationSummary().ToString()) work?

Comment: It might be an `IMvcString` since the OP says its now .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Aaron: It's an extension method. `Html` *is* the parameter.

Comment: @cdhowie, public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummary(
 this HtmlHelper htmlHelper
) yep...missed the 'this'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Html.ValidationSummary()` returns `MvcHtmlString`, not a normal string. So, try this:

```
<% if (MvcHtmlString.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.ValidationSummary())) { %>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that MvcHtmlString has its own version of `IsNullOrEmpty`.

Answer (score 7):

In .net 4.0. [ValidationSummary returns `MvcHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460343.aspx) not `string` as with 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks folks. This topic helped me when I encountered the same error:

```
"Message":"The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null
```

It happened to me that I passed [a **dynamic** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic#overload-resolution-with-arguments-of-type-dynamic) into string.IsNullOrEmpty(), where the parameter was type of *JValue* rather than *string* at runtime. So I have to firstly explicitly convert the parameter to string:

```
var isValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Value);
```

It is a similar case with MvcHtmlString.

Answer (score 0):

In the new MVC, the Html.ValidationSummary() returns a MvcHtmlString, not a normal string.  You could use ValidationSummary().ToString() or ToHtmlString() to make it a string.